# Filter pivot condition inside whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Assume that I have 2 models which called Product and Item and 1 pivot table called product_item, I would like to preview only the non-selected product to the user but it the product is not selected by another user, it should remain available for another user.

```
In the Product Model,
public function items(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}

public function showNonSelectedItem($query,$id){
       return $query->when($id,function($query) use($id){
           $query->where(function($query) use ($id){
                $query->whereHas('item',function($q) use ($id){
                    //  
                });
            });
       });
    }
```

My current database

```
product_item
|product_id |item_id | user_id |
|1          | 2      |  3      |
|2          | 1      |  3      |
|1          | 3      |  2      |


Product
|product_id|product_name|
|1         | MCD        |
|2         | MCD        |
|3         | MCD        |
```

So when the user query getProduct API (getProduct?user_id=2), it should only return the item that he/she has not selected, so in this case, the system should return back the user below record

```
|product_id|product_name|
|2         | MCD        |
|3         | MCD        |
```

Or another example: getProduct?user_id=3

```
|product_id|product_name|
|3         | MCD        |
```

Answer (score 0):

can you select product_items where user_id is null?

In the Product Model,

```
public function nonSelectedItems($user_id){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->where('user_id', '!=' , $user_id);
}
```

call it like so

```
$product->nonSelectedItems($user_id);
```

Comment: hi Cameraon, plese do recheck main thread, I have updated the scenario.

Comment: @MiracleHades I updated the relationship query ,  pass your $user_id to the method and return product items that do not belong to the passed user_id.  Of course you will need to get $user_id from the $request in your api.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```php
 $query->whereHas('items', function($q) {
                   
    $q->whereNull('user_id'); 
                
 });
```

or

you can define a new relation in product model:

```php
public function notSelectedItems() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->whereNull('user_id');

}
```

Comment: hi Ali Afshar, plese do recheck main thread, I have updated the scenario.